# Changing a variable across multiple classes (C# with WPF)

Tags: c#, wpf, variables

I'm making a visual-novel styled game application with a 20-question quiz for users to answer (the application is designed as a revision tool). I want to be able to update the score for every question a user gets correct and display the score within a UI element, but I can't seem to be able to use my playerScore variable within private classes. If I could get a fix for this it would be much appreciated.

This is the current XAML for the window I'm using the variable in:

```
<Window x:Class="COMP4_Project.GameWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="Psych" Height="400" Width="500" ResizeMode="CanMinimize">
<Grid Margin="10">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="50" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="50" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="50" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="180"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="75" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="75" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="17" />
        <RowDefinition Height="113" />
        <RowDefinition Height="80" />
        <RowDefinition Height="33" />
        <RowDefinition Height="33"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="17" />
        <RowDefinition Height="17" />
        <RowDefinition Height="17" />
        <RowDefinition Height="66" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <TextBlock x:Name="WorldName" Grid.Column="1" Margin="0,0,0,0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" TextWrapping="NoWrap" TextAlignment="Left" Text="World: Tunnel Entrance" />
    <TextBlock x:Name="ScoreTracker" Grid.Column="5" Margin="0,0,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" TextAlignment="Left" Text="Score:" />
    <TextBlock x:Name="ScoreCount" Grid.Column="6" Margin="0,0,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" TextAlignment="Left" Text="0" />
    <TextBlock x:Name="Dialogue"  Grid.Column="1" Margin="0,0,0,0" Grid.ColumnSpan="6" Grid.Row="5" TextWrapping="Wrap" TextAlignment="Justify" Text="Where do you want to go? Click on the options below to change your location or click on an NPC to talk to them." />
    <TextBlock x:Name="Option1" Grid.Column="1" Margin="0,0,0,0" Grid.ColumnSpan="6" Grid.Row="6" MouseLeftButtonDown="Option1_MouseLeftButtonDown" Text="   > Go Left" />
    <TextBlock x:Name="Option2" Grid.Column="1" Margin="0,0,0,0" Grid.ColumnSpan="6" Grid.Row="7" MouseLeftButtonDown="Option2_MouseLeftButtonDown" Text="   > Go Right" />
    <TextBlock x:Name="Option3" Grid.Column="1" Margin="0,0,0,0" Grid.ColumnSpan="6" Grid.Row="8" MouseLeftButtonDown="Option3_MouseLeftButtonDown" Text="   > Enter Tunnel" />
    <TextBlock x:Name="Option4" Grid.Column="1" Margin="0,0,0,0" Grid.ColumnSpan="6" Grid.Row="6" MouseLeftButtonDown="Option4_MouseLeftButtonDown"  Text="   > Go Back" Visibility="Hidden" />
    <Image x:Name="Portrait" Source="C:\Psyche\Images\red1.png" Grid.Column="4" Grid.Row="1" Grid.RowSpan="4" Visibility="Hidden" />
    <Image x:Name="Sprite" Source="C:\Psyche\Images\redsprite1.png" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="3" MouseLeftButtonDown="Sprite_MouseLeftButtonDown" />
    <TextBlock x:Name="OptionBegin" Grid.Column="1" Margin="0,0,0,0" Grid.ColumnSpan="6" Grid.Row="6" MouseLeftButtonDown="OptionBegin_MouseLeftButtonDown" Text="   > Begin Test" Visibility="Hidden" />
    <TextBlock x:Name="Q1A1" Grid.Column="1" Margin="0,0,0,0" Grid.ColumnSpan="6" Grid.Row="6" MouseLeftButtonDown="Q1A1_MouseLeftButtonDown"  Text="   > Divergence from Standard Normality" Visibility="Hidden" />
    <TextBlock x:Name="Q1A2" Grid.Column="1" Margin="0,0,0,0" Grid.ColumnSpan="6" Grid.Row="7" MouseLeftButtonDown="Q1A2_MouseLeftButtonDown" Text="   > Deviation from Social Norms" Visibility="Hidden" />
    <TextBlock x:Name="Q1A3" Grid.Column="1" Margin="0,0,0,0" Grid.ColumnSpan="6" Grid.Row="8" MouseLeftButtonDown="Q1A3_MouseLeftButtonDown" Text="   > Damaging Social Negligence" Visibility="Hidden" />
    <TextBlock x:Name="Q1Cont" Grid.Column="1" Margin="0,0,0,0" Grid.ColumnSpan="6" Grid.Row="6" MouseLeftButtonDown="Q1Cont_MouseLeftButtonDown" Text="   > Next question" Visibility="Hidden" />
    <TextBlock x:Name="Q2A1" Grid.Column="1" Margin="0,0,0,0" Grid.ColumnSpan="6" Grid.Row="6" MouseLeftButtonDown="Q2A1_MouseLeftButtonDown"  Text="   > Failure to Function Adequately" Visibility="Hidden" />
    <TextBlock x:Name="Q2A2" Grid.Column="1" Margin="0,0,0,0" Grid.ColumnSpan="6" Grid.Row="7" MouseLeftButtonDown="Q2A2_MouseLeftButtonDown" Text="   > Feeling Fairly Awful" Visibility="Hidden" />
    <TextBlock x:Name="Q2A3" Grid.Column="1" Margin="0,0,0,0" Grid.ColumnSpan="6" Grid.Row="8" MouseLeftButtonDown="Q2A3_MouseLeftButtonDown" Text="   > Failing to Feel Alright" Visibility="Hidden" />
    <TextBlock x:Name="Q2Cont" Grid.Column="1" Margin="0,0,0,0" Grid.ColumnSpan="6" Grid.Row="6" MouseLeftButtonDown="Q2Cont_MouseLeftButtonDown" Text="   > Next question" Visibility="Hidden" />
</Grid>
```

And this is my codebehind, including everything up to the second question:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace COMP4_Project
{

public class WorldVariables
{
    public int[] worldLocale = { 0, 1, 2, 3 };
    public string worldName;
    public int playerScore = 0;
    public string playerName;
}

/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for GameWindow.xaml
/// </summary>  

public partial class GameWindow : Window
{
    public GameWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        // Set background image for window
        ImageBrush myBrush = new ImageBrush();
        myBrush.ImageSource =
            new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"C:\Psyche\Images\background0.png", UriKind.Absolute));
        this.Background = myBrush;

        // Ensures non-player character sprite is visible on launching the game window
        Sprite.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
    }

    private void Option1_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        // Change background image
        this.Background = new ImageBrush(new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"C:\Psyche\Images\background1.png")));
        // Hide character sprite
        Sprite.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
        // Hide character portrait (should not be visible regardless, this is simply a failsafe)
        Portrait.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
        // Change visible options
        Option1.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
        Option2.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
        Option3.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
        Option4.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        // Alter WorldName field to match change in scene
        WorldName.Text = "Location: Stream";
        // Alter dialogue to match change in scene
        Dialogue.Text = "There's a tree across the stream. Not much else around, though.";

    }

    private void Option2_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        this.Background = new ImageBrush(new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"C:\Psyche\Images\background2.png")));
        Sprite.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
        Portrait.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
        Option1.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
        Option2.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
        Option3.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
        Option4.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        WorldName.Text = "Location: Forest";
        Dialogue.Text = "It's pretty dark here due to the dense canopy of trees overhead. Kind of creepy when you think about it.";
    }

    private void Option3_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        this.Background = new ImageBrush(new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"C:\Psyche\Images\background3.png")));
        Sprite.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
        Portrait.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
        Option1.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
        Option2.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
        Option3.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
        Option4.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        WorldName.Text = "Location: Tunnel";
        Dialogue.Text = "There's nothing here, except a small dot of light in the distance. That might be the exit, but it's too far to check safely.";
    }

    private void Option4_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        this.Background = new ImageBrush(new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"C:\Psyche\Images\background0.png")));
        Sprite.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        Portrait.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
        Option1.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        Option2.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        Option3.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        Option4.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
        // Revert worldname to previous text
        WorldName.Text = "Location: Tunnel Entrance";
        // Revert dialogue to previous text
        Dialogue.Text = "Where do you want to go? Click on the options below to change your location or click on an NPC to talk to them.";
    }

    private void Sprite_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        // Hide character sprite
        Sprite.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
        // Show character portrait
        Portrait.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        // Hide all previous options to avoid overlap
        Option1.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
        Option2.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
        Option3.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
        Option4.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
        // Dialogue text changes to show NPC dialogue
        Dialogue.Text = "Red: Oh, hey playerName, you want to revise your knowledge?";
        // Show option to begin test
        OptionBegin.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
    }

    private void OptionBegin_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        // Change dialogue for each question
        Dialogue.Text = "Red: Alright, first question. What does DSN stand for?";
        // Hide option to begin test as this is no longer needed
        OptionBegin.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
        // Show three new options as answers to question
        Q1A1.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        Q1A2.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        Q1A3.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
    }

    private void Q1A1_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        Dialogue.Text = "Red: Not quite. Why don't we try another question?.";
        Q1A1.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
        Q1A2.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
        Q1A3.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
        Q1Cont.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
    }

    private void Q1A2_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        // Can't access variable from here? Could be a problem
        // playerScore = playerScore + 1;
        Dialogue.Text = "Red: Correct! Let's try another one, shall we?";
        Q1A1.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
        Q1A2.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
        Q1A3.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
        Q1Cont.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
    }

    private void Q1A3_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        Dialogue.Text = "Red: Not quite. Why don't we try another question?.";
        Q1A1.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
        Q1A2.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
        Q1A3.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
        Q1Cont.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
    }

    private void Q1Cont_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        Q1Cont.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
        Dialogue.Text = "Red: What does FFA stand for?";
        Q2A1.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        Q2A2.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        Q2A3.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
    }
```

As you can see in Q1A2_MouseLeftButtonDown, I've included my intentions for the playerScore variable within a comment, as it won't function when I actually try to use it.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add an instance of `WorldVariables` to your `GameWindow` class:

```
public partial class GameWindow : Window
{
    private readonly WorldVariables worldVariables = new WorldVariables();
```

You can then access the `playerScore` field inside the event handler:

```
private void Q1A2_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    worldVariables.playerScore = playerScore + 1;
```

Unless this was a simple oversight you probably need to study the difference between classes, instances and static variables a bit more to get a better understanding of what is going on. A good starting point is [Classes and Structs (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173109.aspx) on MSDN.